# proof for trapezoid within triangle conundrum

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I've recently been working on some geometry problems involving non-isosceles trapezoids and stumbled upon an interesting discovery which seems to hold true for all cases I've tried, but I don't have the expertise to construct a proof.
Here's the thing:

1. take any random triangle ABC
2. choose two points Q on edge AB and P on edge AC such that QP || BC. We now have constructed a trapezoid QBCP
3. find K the intersection point of the trapezoid's diagonals.
4. The line AK will perfectly bisect QP and BC in the middle. This is what requires proof.

I am very interested if somebody can construct a proof for this.
Thanks

[illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDZ4d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $AK\cap QP=\{M\}$, $AK\cap BC=\{N\}$, $QM=a$, $MP=b$, $BN=c$ and $NC=d$.

Thus, by similarity of triangles we obtain:
$$\frac{a}{c}=\frac{AM}{AN}=\frac{b}{d}$$ and
$$\frac{a}{d}=\frac{MK}{KN}=\frac{b}{c},$$ which gives $a=b$ and $c=d$.

Comment: Thanks, that seems correct. I didn't realize that the two pairs of opposing triangles defined by the trapezoid's diagonals, which share vertex K are also similar. That explains it.